# HTML Table Problem - rowspan, colspan etc

Tags: html, row, col

[image]

how can i reach my goal to build a table like this one on the image - i tried a lot of things with row- or colspan but cannot get it work.

The field with the blue background is the problem.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?
You need to use the colspan and rowspan at appropriate positions that I have used at.

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1px" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Tr</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:skyblue;" colspan="7">value</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Tr</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:skyblue;" colspan="7">value</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Tr</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
    <td rowspan="2">value</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:skyblue;" colspan="7">value</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```